# Convert between string and enum using Convert.ChangeType

Tags: c#, casting, expression, expression-trees

I have a class which represent a generic filter expression

```
public class SimpleFilter : BaseRuleExpression
{
    public string field { get; set; }

    public string op { get; set; }

    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

When I need to apply a filter on a IQueryable I simply convert this filter to a LambdaExpression object and apply this filter to a DbSet instance like in the following example

```
var filter = new SimpleFilter() {
    field = "CustomerID",
    op = "eq",
    value = "1"
};
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter( typeof( Customer ), "x" );
IQueryable<Customer> query = _ctx.Customers.AsQueryable<Customer>();
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> lambda = (Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>)filter.ToExpression( query, pe );
var cList = _ctx.Customers.AsQueryable<Customer>().Where( lambda )
```

The `ToExpression` method is as follow:

```
MemberExpression memberAccess = GetMemberExpression( field, pe );
ConstantExpression filter = Expression.Constant( Convert.ChangeType( data, memberAccess.Type ) );
Operator condition = (Operator)StringEnum.Parse( typeof( Operator ), op );
LambdaExpression lambda = BuildLambdaExpression( memberAccess, filter, pe, condition, data );
```

The problem happens on the following line because the `Convert.ChangeType` method has no direct conversion between `string` and `enum`.

```
ConstantExpression filter = Expression.Constant( Convert.ChangeType( data, memberAccess.Type ) );
```

How can I solve this problem? Can I check for type enum in target and eventually convert first the `string` in `int`?

Comment: You can rely on Enum.Parse or Enum.TryParse to convert a string into a enum and directly convert (or even just cast) this enum into an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that getting a converter from `TypeDescriptor` is a more reliable way to convert between various types. This is the strategy used by technologies like ASP.NET MVC Model Binding.

```
void Main()
{
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Foo));
    Foo f = (Foo)converter.ConvertFromString("A");
    Console.WriteLine(f); // A
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public enum Foo {A, B, C}
```

Comment: +1. I just went back to one of my codes and replaced special handling of Enums/DateTime/Guids from string conversion by your snippet. Guess what All tests were passing expcept only one. But got rid of 20 lines of code by just 3 lines.